# View Tweets from a specific country?

Tags: twitter

I'd like to know who's talking about what within my country at this minute, real time - to get an idea of what topics, so I can join in. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to go about it is to use [**Twitter Advanced Search**](https://twitter.com/search-advanced). There you can search for twitter conversations while limiting the search to tweets from users near a certain country or a city.

[image: Twitter Advanced Search]
Advanced Twitter users memorize Twitter's query language and type advanced compounded search queries directly into the search field at the top of the Twitter User Interface screen.

[image]

Another advantage for mastering Twitter's query language is the ability to filter the search results not only by location but also by virality, for example: "show all tweets from the UK which have more than 100 retweets or 200 likes"